# How to add the X-Total-Count header with Loopback 4?

Tags: typescript, http-headers, loopbackjs, loopback4

I am using React-Admin and I need to add the X-Total-Count in order to manage the pagination, I know it was possible with Loopback3 but I didn't find anything for lb4.

Comment: For solution please refer : https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/5571.
As the @Yvan found the solutiuon.